# Cleaner way to remove item form one list and add to another (novice)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a homework where i got to create a simple game where a man enters a "building" and has to open a few doors and move on. In order to do that he must take items from the ground and add them to his inventory.

Please see an example of my code:

```
inventory = []
ground = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

def take_item(item):
    if item in ground:
        inventory.append(item)
        ground.remove(item)
        print "Item taken"
    else:
        print "There is nothing here"

take_item('item1')
print inventory
print ground
take_item('item1')
```

Result is ok:

```
Item taken 
inventory = ['item1'] 
ground = ['item2', 'item3']
There is nothing here
```

My question is if there is a cleaner and/or more pythonish way to remove items from one list and add it to another one?

Thank you.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `list.remove` removes only one occurrence. What's the error?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I don't see a loop in there.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Moment of blindness, misread `if` as a `for`. :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing a working code, which usually belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's pythonic enough I think ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Will definitely use "try" and "except" when the time comes. Cannot vote answers up as my rep doesn't allow that yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is generally fine, no glaring issues with it, though depending on who you ask, it may be more pythonic to try something and then throw an exception if it doesn't work and `return` rather than just printing, like so:

```
def take_item(item):
    try:
        ground.remove(item)
        inventory.append(item)
        return "Item Taken"
    except ValueError:
        return "There is nothing here"
```

Though general globals are a bit of a no-no, so I would advise including them as inputs and making this more modular:

```
def take(item, ground, inventory):
```

and then return everything all at once, which would make the whole function look something like this:

```
    def take_item(item, ground, inventory):
    try:
        ground.remove(item)
        inventory.append(item)
        message = "Item Taken"
    except ValueError:
        message = "There is nothing here"
    return message, ground, inventory
```

But your first try was pretty great, no need to optimize code until you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try to use 'try' and 'except' when i get to that. Cannot vote answers up as my rep doesn't allow that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, afaict, your solution looks perfectly fine and pythonic to me.

```
def take_item(item):
    if item in ground:
        inventory.append(item)
        ground.remove(item)
```

is a good algorithm, in that it is very explicit about what it does, so when you or someone else reads it, he can understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Cannot vote answers up as my rep doesn't allow that yet

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) shows the time-complexity of remove in `list` is O(n), is better to try `set`  in this case.

Comment: It's not clear that a set would work in this case. Imagine the case of having multiple objects in either your inventory or the ground, which seems quite possible.